# How do I include a Javascript library in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've downloaded a javascript file called jquery.jsPlumb-1.2.6 and placed in my public/javascripts directory.

I want access to this file in one particular html.erb and several js.erbs. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in the HEAD section of your page (recommended): This function will return references to the JavaScript files created by the rails command in your public/javascripts directory. Using it is recommended as the browser can then cache the libraries instead of fetching all the functions anew on every request.

Or you can use`<%= javascript_include_tag 'prototype' %>`: As above, but will only include the Prototype core library, which means you are able to use all basic AJAX functionality. For the Scriptaculous-based JavaScript helpers, like visual effects, autocompletion, drag and drop and so on, you should use the method described above.

More info here mate.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html

Comment: But I have downloaded a file that is not prototype or jquery... How do I include a file named sdfsdfdsf.js is my question. Not how to include prototype.

Comment: i think it would be <%= javascript_include_tag 'example.js' %>

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2017, `:defaults` does not appear to be a special argument to `javascript_include_tag` (or, at least not in Rails 5) — ActionView simply tries to load `defaults.js` from the asset pipeline.